# Are there stats for the Roman Scutum in any supplement?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, d20-system, shield

The Roman Scutum was a shield much like a tower shield but smaller and lighter:

[image: Roman Legionnaire re-enactor carrying his Scutum]

While a D&D [Tower Shield](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/armor.htm#shieldTower) is 45 lbs. and can't bash, a Scutum was typically about 22 lbs. (10 kg) and [was used for bashing](https://youtu.be/rDmVw4aj0SQ?t=3m45s), among other things. The next shield smaller in D&D is the [Heavy Shield](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/armor.htm#shieldHeavyWoodenorSteel), but the Heavy Shield is about 30% lighter than a Scutum and can't grant you cover, while a Scutum [can be used for cover](https://youtu.be/ygsa6iO8X9o?t=1m48s).

The Scutum seems to be somewhere in between these two standard D&D shields.

Is there a shield anywhere in D&D 3.5 or a d20 supplement that properly models or represents the Scutum, in size and in granting cover and permitting a shield bash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The rules

The answer is no, there are no shields granting cover on its own and allowing to bash with them. Having such a shield would destroy the balance because tower shields would become obsolete in the face of a shield that does *both* and heavy shields would be at least challenged, depending on your playstyle. I am also not aware of any official publication that lists a scutum shield.

## How to handle a scutum inside the rules

- The scutum *can* be seen as heavy shield. It is lighter than a tower shield and does not provide full cover until you use a tactic like the *[testudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testudo_formation)*, that makes use of interlocking those shields and protecting a whole block of soldiers.
- The scutum *can* be seen as a tower shield. It's almost the height of a soldier and should provide cover if used correctly. However, it was never actually intended to be used to bash *in the way that D&D defines a shield bash*. D&D defines a shield bash as an offensive maneuver in which the shield loses it's protective qualities and instead is used to hurt an enemy. The scene linked in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDmVw4aj0SQ&feature=youtu.be&t=3m45s) is exactly the opposite. The roman soldier uses the full protective capacity of the shield against one enemy while striking for the other. The enemy the shield was used *against* took *no* "damage" in D&D terms. Using a shield this way is a very useful combat tactic and certainly shoves a more fragile warrior a few feet, but it is *not* giving up defense for additional damage. It's not a shield bash as D&D defines it and I doubt that the romans ever taught it to be used the D&D way.

Either way is fine, mechanically. You decide.

## Suggestions

There are a few feats for fighters that go in that direction. Phalanx fighting for example. If you wanted to mimic Roman Legionnaires, you could house rule a feat for testudo formation fighting. I think it would fit right in with the other formation fighting feats. Rulewise the shield would be a heavy wooden shield and using testudo formation could grant cover instead of the bonus AC that other shield formation feats grant.

Comment: I took this to [meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5625/players-who-see-it-differently-are-simply-wrong).

Comment: Comments are not for arguing with the answer.